# Concat arabic and english string with string.Format()

Tags: c#, string, arabic, latin

Have some trouble with concat two string.

```
return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
            IdWithSubType,

            ExtraInfo.Any(info => info.InfoType == UniExtraInfoType.Alias)
            ? string.Format(" ({0})", string.Join(",", ExtraInfo.First(info => info.InfoType == UniExtraInfoType.Alias).Info))
            : "",

            Context != null
            ? string.Format(" ({0})", Context.IdWithSubType)
            : "");
```

it's ok when IdWithSubType, extrainfo and context has latin or kirillic symbols, but IdWithSubType can be arabic, and concat with that is wrong.
e.g.100252575)طائرات هليكوبت@vk.com)
arabic and other symbols mixed, but i need something like "here arabic string"                    (100252575@vk.com. it would be great if this problem have solve with String.Format. Hope for your help. Thank you

Comment: What encoding is it all in? .Net strings are utf-16

Comment: default encoding entire solution utf-8.

Comment: Ok. I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to ask with this question

Comment: Yes using string format will help combine two strings that were encoded use two different encoding.  string output = string.Format("{0} {1}", string1, string2);

Comment: @jdweng what encoding you are talking about? This seem to be regular rtl/ltr question rather than about encodings...

Comment: It is encoding issues. The issue is a string that go left to right with one that goes right to left.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely no encoding issues appear there, just how RTL (right-to-left) string follows arrangement as part of LTR (left-to-right) string.

There's 2 characters which commonly used in bidirectional formatting to mark either LTR & RTL part, assigned as [`0x200e`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm) (LTR) & [`0x200f`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm) (RTL). In this case, use `0x200e` to mark end of RTL part (in Arabic) and starting LTR part:

```
string leftToRight = ((char)0x200E).ToString();

// using string.Format
return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
            IdWithSubType,
            leftToRight,

            ExtraInfo.Any(info => info.InfoType == UniExtraInfoType.Alias)
            ? string.Format(" ({0})", string.Join(",", ExtraInfo.First(info => info.InfoType == UniExtraInfoType.Alias).Info))
            : "",

            Context != null
            ? string.Format(" ({0})", Context.IdWithSubType)
            : "");,

// alternative: using string.Join
return string.Join(leftToRight, IdWithSubType,
            ExtraInfo.Any(info => info.InfoType == UniExtraInfoType.Alias)
            ? string.Format(" ({0})", string.Join(",", ExtraInfo.First(info => info.InfoType == UniExtraInfoType.Alias).Info))
            : "",

            Context != null
            ? string.Format(" ({0})", Context.IdWithSubType)
            : "");,
```

Demo: [.NET Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WKYBAz)

Similar issues:

[incorrect right to left concatenation english and Arabic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146491/incorrect-right-to-left-concatenation-english-and-arabic)

[Problem creating correct path concatenating left to right with right to left sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475067/problem-creating-correct-path-concatenating-left-to-right-with-right-to-left-sec)